# Modal button added to html table rows, while table data is being imported in from json file

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, bootstrap-modal

```js
$('.toggleModal').on('click', function (e) {
  
  $('.modal').toggleClass('active');
  
});
```

```css
html{
            font:0.75em/1.5 sans-serif;
            color:#333;
            background-color:#fff;
            padding:1em;
        }

        /* Tables */
table{
    width:100%;
            margin-bottom:1em;
            border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px;
        }
th{
    font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#ddd;
        }
        
td{
    padding:0.5em;
            border:1px solid black;
   
        }
  
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ddd;
 
}
  
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}  

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ios7-icon';
  src: url("//ios7-icon-font-demo.herokuapp.com/fonts/ios7-icon.woff") format("woff"), url("//ios7-icon-font-demo.herokuapp.com/fonts/ios7-icon.ttf") format("ttf");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue' !important;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #007aff;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

section {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
section p {
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}



button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   background: LightBlue; 
  color: #007aff;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  /* &:nth-child(even){ */
   /* background: white; */
  /* } */
  /*  &:last-child {
      border-color: red;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }*/
}
button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
button.button-border {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 12px 8px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #007aff;
}
 button.button-border:hover { 
   background: #007aff; 
   color: #ffffff; 
  text-decoration: none; 
 } 
 button.button-success { 
  /color: #4dd865; */
   border-color: #4dd865; 
 } 
 button.button-success:hover { 
   background: #4dd865; 
 } 
 button.button-error { 
   color: #ff3b30; 
  border-color: #ff3b30; 
 } 
 button.button-error:hover { 
   background: #ff3b30; 
 } 

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 430px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.modal.active {
  display: block;
}
.modal header {
  position: relative;
}
.modal h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.modal .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: circle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: inherit;
  -webkit-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -moz-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -ms-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -o-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tablestyle.css">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="datasource/people.json"> </script>

<script>

 $(function() {

   var people = [];

   $.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.hours + "</td>" + " </tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });

   });

});
</script>

<body>
<table id="userdata" rules="groups" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <thead>

        <tr>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th>EmployeeNum</th>
                        <th>EmployeeName</th>
                        <th>ChargeNum</th>
                        <th>Hours</th>
                </tr>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>

    </thead>
    <tr id="1">
        <td><button class="button-border toggleModal">
      <span class="icon"></span> Timesheet Approval</button> </td>
        <td>123</td>
                <td>Mike</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>40</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="2">
        <td><button class="button-border toggleModal">
      <span class="icon"></span> Timesheet Approval</button></td>
        <td>EmployeeNum</td>
                <td>EmployeeName</td>
                <td>ChargeNum</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="3">
        <td><button class="button-border toggleModal">
      <span class="icon"></span> Timesheet Approval</button></td>
        <td>EmployeeNum</td>
                <td>EmployeeName</td>
                <td>ChargeNum</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
    </tr>

        <tr id="4">
        <td><button class="button-border toggleModal">
      <span class="icon"></span> Timesheet Approval</button></td>
        <td>EmployeeNum</td>
                <td>EmployeeName</td>
                <td>ChargeNum</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
    </tr>

</table>
 <div class="modal">

    <header>

      <button class="close toggleModal">Close</button>
    </header>

    <section>
      <p>To approve the timesheet and submit it to WAM press "Approve", to decline the timesheet for later viewing press "Disapprove"</p>
    </section>

    <button class="button-border button-success toggleModal">
      <span class="icon"></span> Approve </button>

    <button class="button-border button-error pull-right toggleModal">
      <span class="icon">< </span> Disapprove </button>
                <!-- <script> $(docuemnt).ready(function(){ -->
                        <!-- var rowCount = $('table#tableId tr:#a').index() + 1; -->
                        <!-- $("#a").style.color = "red"}); -->
                        <!-- </script> -->

  </div>


  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

In this code I still have my original table info. The snippet is not working properly for some reason so I have added screenshots of the table a modal view. 
[1. table view with buttons going to the rows with users declared inside the html file, while the blank rows are the users being imported from a json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0JKG.png) and [2. This is the window that comes up after pressing the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwjP4.png)

I know there is definitely a way to make this code cleaner and better. Is there a way I can make these buttons work before I attempt to clean up the code? End goal here is to remove the table data completely from HTML and only import the data from a json(which will later be replaced by a db when everything is running smoothly)

edit: this is the json code I am using. I took this example and was trying to implement it in my table, so the fields do not match up. I left the firstname field blank as to leave room for the button on the table, I am not sure if this is the correct way to approach this or not.

```
{
   "person": [
   {
       "firstName": " ",
       "lastName": "11",
       "job": "James",
       "roll": 20,
       "hours": 20
   },
   {
       "firstName": " ",
       "lastName": "Wayne",
       "job": "Playboy",
       "roll": 30,
       "hours": 40
   },
   {
       "firstName": " ",
       "lastName": "Parker",
       "job": "Photographer",
       "roll": 40,
       "hours": 40
   }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I ran the code snippet and your buttons seem to work properly -- what's the issue here?

Comment: @J.Chen - The buttons work for the table rows that have data from the html page, the buttons do not appear in the rows when using data from a json file. Look at the two images I added as a reference.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Right now your javascript code inside the script tag isn't creating a button -- you need to add the button HTML within the first `<td>`. If this doesn't make sense, could you also post your json data? That way I can write a runnable snippet

Comment: @J.Chen - I have added the json code that I am using, along with a paragraph above the code. I tried implementing the button through my script where there is nothing in the first <td>, it was originally f.firstname.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a code snippet below. I commented out your original `$.getJson` function and loaded the contents of `people.json` into an object. I then iterated through, used jQuery to create the buttons and rows, and appended it to `#userdata tbody`. Let me know if you have questions.

```js
$('.toggleModal').on('click', function (e) {
  
  $('.modal').toggleClass('active');
  
});
```

```css
html{
            font:0.75em/1.5 sans-serif;
            color:#333;
            background-color:#fff;
            padding:1em;
        }

        /* Tables */
table{
    width:100%;
            margin-bottom:1em;
            border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px;
        }
th{
    font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#ddd;
        }
        
td{
    padding:0.5em;
            border:1px solid black;
   
        }
  
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ddd;
 
}
  
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}  

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ios7-icon';
  src: url("//ios7-icon-font-demo.herokuapp.com/fonts/ios7-icon.woff") format("woff"), url("//ios7-icon-font-demo.herokuapp.com/fonts/ios7-icon.ttf") format("ttf");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue' !important;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #007aff;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

section {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
section p {
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}



button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   background: LightBlue; 
  color: #007aff;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  /* &:nth-child(even){ */
   /* background: white; */
  /* } */
  /*  &:last-child {
      border-color: red;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }*/
}
button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
button.button-border {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 12px 8px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #007aff;
}
 button.button-border:hover { 
   background: #007aff; 
   color: #ffffff; 
  text-decoration: none; 
 } 
 button.button-success { 
  /color: #4dd865; */
   border-color: #4dd865; 
 } 
 button.button-success:hover { 
   background: #4dd865; 
 } 
 button.button-error { 
   color: #ff3b30; 
  border-color: #ff3b30; 
 } 
 button.button-error:hover { 
   background: #ff3b30; 
 } 

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 430px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.modal.active {
  display: block;
}
.modal header {
  position: relative;
}
.modal h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.modal .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: circle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: inherit;
  -webkit-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -moz-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -ms-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -o-text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>

 $(function() {

   var people = [];
   let data = {
                 "person": [
                 {
                     "firstName": " ",
                     "lastName": "11",
                     "job": "James",
                     "roll": 20,
                     "hours": 20
                 },
                 {
                     "firstName": " ",
                     "lastName": "Wayne",
                     "job": "Playboy",
                     "roll": 30,
                     "hours": 40
                 },
                 {
                     "firstName": " ",
                     "lastName": "Parker",
                     "job": "Photographer",
                     "roll": 40,
                     "hours": 40
                 }
                 ]
                };
                
  for (let i = 0; i < data.person.length; i++) {
    let person = data.person[i];
    let row = $(`<tr></tr>`);
    // Create a jQuery object for the button cell
    let buttonCell = $(`<td></td>`);
    // Add the actual button to the cell
    buttonCell.append(`
      <button class="button-border toggleModal">
        <span class="icon"></span> Timesheet Approval
      </button>`);
    // Add the whole button cell to the row
    row.append(buttonCell);
    row.append(`<td>` + person.lastName + `</td>`);
    row.append(`<td>` + person.job + `</td>`);
    row.append(`<td>` + person.roll + `</td>`);
    row.append(`<td>` + person.hours + `</td>`);
    $("#userdata tbody").append(row);
  }
  
  // We have to attach click handlers to the new buttons that were created
  $('.toggleModal').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.modal').toggleClass('active');
  });
  
  /*
   $.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.hours + "</td>" + " </tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });

   });
   */
});
</script>

<body>
<table id="userdata" rules="groups" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <thead>

        <tr>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th>EmployeeNum</th>
                        <th>EmployeeName</th>
                        <th>ChargeNum</th>
                        <th>Hours</th>
                </tr>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>

    </thead>
    <tr id="1">
        <td><button class="button-border toggleModal">
      <span class="icon"></span> Timesheet Approval</button> </td>
        <td>123</td>
                <td>Mike</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>40</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="2">
        <td><button class="button-border toggleModal">
      <span class="icon"></span> Timesheet Approval</button></td>
        <td>EmployeeNum</td>
                <td>EmployeeName</td>
                <td>ChargeNum</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="3">
        <td><button class="button-border toggleModal">
      <span class="icon"></span> Timesheet Approval</button></td>
        <td>EmployeeNum</td>
                <td>EmployeeName</td>
                <td>ChargeNum</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
    </tr>

        <tr id="4">
        <td><button class="button-border toggleModal">
      <span class="icon"></span> Timesheet Approval</button></td>
        <td>EmployeeNum</td>
                <td>EmployeeName</td>
                <td>ChargeNum</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
    </tr>

</table>
 <div class="modal">

    <header>

      <button class="close toggleModal">Close</button>
    </header>

    <section>
      <p>To approve the timesheet and submit it to WAM press "Approve", to decline the timesheet for later viewing press "Disapprove"</p>
    </section>

    <button class="button-border button-success toggleModal">
      <span class="icon"></span> Approve </button>

    <button class="button-border button-error pull-right toggleModal">
      <span class="icon">< </span> Disapprove </button>
                <!-- <script> $(docuemnt).ready(function(){ -->
                        <!-- var rowCount = $('table#tableId tr:#a').index() + 1; -->
                        <!-- $("#a").style.color = "red"}); -->
                        <!-- </script> -->

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement this to hold the table data in json? I can do the table data in html with the buttons, but need the data for the tables to be imported in.

Comment: Yes, your original code with `$.getJSON('people.json', function(data)` should work properly. Assuming your file structure is set up correctly, it will read contents of `people.json` into `data` object.